# Vue.js laravel display data with single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, vue.js

I am new to vue.js and i am trying to display a single array from a json array data returned . This is my array

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "id":1,
      "meter_ID":"0000080123",
      "username":"bobin56",
      "apartment":"Slipway Towers",
      "mobile":"0712291552",
      "power":"100",
      "created_at":"2016-12-04 00:00:00",
      "updated_at":"2016-12-04 00:00:00"
   }
}
```

I tried to display when array is having multiple values according to the documentation like this and it works .

```
<ul>
     <li v-for="meter in balanceStore.meterBalance">{{ meter.apartment }}</li>
</ul>
```

This is my object :-

```
state: Object
balanceStore: Object
meterBalance: Object
apartment: "Slipway Towers"
created_at: "2016-12-04 00:00:00"
id: 1
meter_ID: "0000080123"
mobile: "0712291552"
power: "100"
updated_at: "2016-12-04 00:00:00"
username: "bobin56"
```

But now i am wondering how to do it for a single array data as i can't find it in the documentation .

Comment: What do you mean by  single array data ?

Comment: Hi , @saurabh Thanks for helping . i mean like displaying just apartment and not the whole data array . at the moment i have <li v-for= key in balanceStore.meterBalance"> {{key}} </li> where it will display all the values . i just want one value . Thanks .

Comment: which one value you want to display if it is coming from an array, You can show first one like this: `{{balanceStore && balanceStore.meterBalance[0]}}`. Have I misunderstood you?